# Target named 'Build' not found

Tags: .net, msbuild, f#, f#-fake

I'm trying to build simple F# console program, using FAKE build tool which include MSBuild tool, but I got the following:

> FSProject.fsproj: error : Target named 'Build' not found in the project.

How can I resolve this?

I'm using VS2013 and .NET 4.5

Comment: Show us the contents of the `fsproj` file. It seems likely you are missing an `Import` or the required target file. Does `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.targets` exist?

Comment: @mikez: if i undestood, VS does not include such targets by default. So should i manually edit *.fproj files for MSBuild?
Also, i'm interesting in FAKE build tool (MSBuild is part of it).

Comment: You should not have to edit the fsproj file to build if you used the basic project that comes with VS and are building with MSBuild or VS. "Build" is not a target that exists by default. It is defined in the Microsoft.Common.targets file which is imported by the Microsoft.FSharp.targets file.

Comment: @mikez: So what should i do for building my projects/solution?
can u show me an example?

Comment: Does the building work if you create a new project from scratch?

Comment: @TomasPetricek: you can create simple console F# project, then try to build it using MSBuild.

Comment: Can you try this solution? [How to configure MSBuild to locate the F# build targets](http://nikosbaxevanis.com/blog/2013/10/04/how-to-configure-msbuild-to-locate-the-f-number-build-targets/)

Comment: the problem was caused by the fact that I used MSBuild tool from `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, but VS2013 actually packed with new MSBuild v12.0 `[ProgramFilesX86]\MSBuild\12.0\bin`.

Comment: and if anyone use FAKE build tool, y can fix MSBuild path according to https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/develop/src/app/FAKE/app.config#L4

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi So were you calling msbuild directly from the command line or through Fake? You should post your comments above as an answer, but you should clarify in your question exactly what command was failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that FAKE build tool I used, uses older MSBuild tool version from `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`. But VS2013 F# projects can be builded only with new version of MSBuild installed in `[ProgramFilesX86]\MSBuild\12.0\bin`.

So, how to fix this issue in FAKE tool:

You should change FAKE.exe.config according to [this](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/develop/src/app/FAKE/app.config#L4)

i.e. change `MSBuildPath` setting to actual path.

Comment: Actually this should be fixed in the current develop branch.

Answer (score 0):

To found the issue, you can created your own Build-target to the fsproj-file first:

```xml
<Target Name="Build">
    <Message Text="Ext = $(MSBuildExtensionsPath)" />
    <Message Text="Tools = $(MSBuildToolsVersion)" />
    <Message Text="msb32 = $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)" />
    <Message Text="targ = $(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)" />
    <Message Text="fs = $(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
    <Message Text="vs = $(VisualStudioVersion)" />
</Target>
```

The issue is probably that there is a condition saying something like

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '11.0'">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

but with recent Visual Studio the condition is not met or the path is actually somewhere else,
like in `VisualStudio\v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\FSharp\` and not in `VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\` so as a quick fix
you can fallback it to something else like

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '11.0' And Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\')">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' != '11.0' And Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\FSharp\')">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```